# HTML control functionalities

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `select` html element

like this:

```
<select>
   <option id="US" value="US">
   </option>
   <option id="Canada" value="Canada">
   </option>
 </select>
```

I want two things:

1. I want to post request to server on selection of option
2. And I want to put html elements inside option

Are these two things possible (for all browsers, especially modern browser)?

Comment: `And I want to put html elements inside option.`, Which elements, give example

Comment: @Tushar html checkbox etc.

Comment: Unclear. What have you tried .? You taged jquery, but I don't see any code.

Comment: if you want to change the text between `<option>` , then use `$('select option').text('My text');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `change` event on `select`.

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '',
        data: {
            ...
        }
    });
});
```

Embedding HTML inside `option`.**NOT RECOMMENDED**

```
$('option:first').html('<div>Hello</div>');
```

Comment: and what about embedding html inside option?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery :

```
$(function() {
  $('select').on('change', function() {
    $.post('your/path', $(this).val(), function(data) {
      var option = $('select option[value="'+$('select').val()+'"]');
      // Do what you want with your option
    };
  });
});
```